# np.reshape returns error 'ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

The array that I'm trying to enter has length 240.

I've tried:

```
r = np.reshape(array, (3, 80))
```

because I read somewhere else on this site that the rows and columns entered into reshape have to multiply to the array length.

However, I'm still getting the error:

> ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example that causes this error?

Comment: Do you see why that example isn't reproducible? For the sake time, what's the output of `expanded_images[0].shape`? Arrays can have multiple dimensions.

Comment: The output is (240, 215, 3).

Comment: Think about how many elements you have in that array. Then think about whether you can have all of those in a `(3, 80)` array.

Answer (score 1):

You said you have additional dimensions in your array so you need to keep them:

```
>>> arr = np.random.random((240, 215, 3))
>>> reshaped = np.reshape(arr, (3, 80, arr.shape[1], arr.shape[2]))
>>> reshaped.shape
(3, 80, 215, 3)
```

or using unpacking to avoid hardcoding the dimensions:

```
>>> reshaped = np.reshape(arr, (3, 80, *arr.shape[1:]))
(3, 80, 215, 3)
```

If you want the last dimension to be ravelled then you could also use `-1` as last axis in your reshape:

```
>>> reshaped_ravel = np.reshape(arr, (3, 80, -1))
>>> reshaped_ravel.shape
(3, 80, 645)
```